# Eclipse Helios does not recognize Java code beside Scala code

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, eclipse-3.6

I imported a Maven project (File > Import... > Maven > Existing Maven Projects) using Scala source code as well as Java source code into Eclipse Helios. While the Scala source get's recognized correctly the Java code is not recognized.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

How can I make Eclipse understand the Java part as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried adding the `/src/main/java/` folder as a *source folder* via:

   > [right click] > Build Path > Use as Source Folder

   This should result in a `<classpathentry>` in your `.classpath` file.
2. Sometimes the `.project` file misses the *Java nature* completely:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <projectDescription>
       ...
       <natures>
           ...
           <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
       </natures>
   </projectDescription>
   ```

*Note: your package / project explorer view might be configured to filter '.* resources'. You can also access these files via <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.*